# Parsing the correct fields with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a very long JSON that I'm trying to parse using JQ. Basically, the only fields I really need is the data that is contained within FieldId: 83, FieldId: 84, and FieldId: 85. All the other fields are basically irrelevant for the purposes of this exercise. So just the data from those three fields.

How would I do that?

```
[
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 54,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "What school did you attend?",
                "FieldGroupId": 12,
                "FieldGroupName": "College",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "T",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": 75,
                "availableValues": null,
                "isExportable": true
            },
            "FieldId": 54,
            "FieldGroupId": 12,
            "assignedValue": null
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 63,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "What year did you graduate?",
                "FieldGroupId": 12,
                "FieldGroupName": "College",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "S",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": null,
                "availableValues": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "2017",
                        "parentValueId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "2018",
                        "parentValueId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "2019",
                        "parentValueId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "2020",
                        "parentValueId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "name": "2021",
                        "parentValueId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "name": "2022",
                        "parentValueId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "name": "2023",
                        "parentValueId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 8,
                        "name": "2024",
                        "parentValueId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 11,
                        "name": "2025",
                        "parentValueId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 12,
                        "name": "2026",
                        "parentValueId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 9,
                        "name": "Already graduated",
                        "parentValueId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 10,
                        "name": "Not applicable",
                        "parentValueId": null
                    }
                ],
                "isExportable": true
            },
            "FieldId": 63,
            "FieldGroupId": 12,
            "assignedValue": null
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 81,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "School Organization",
                "FieldGroupId": 12,
                "FieldGroupName": "College",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "S",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": null,
                "availableValues": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Administration/Administrators",
                        "parentValueId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Class Representatives",
                        "parentValueId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "Greek Life",
                        "parentValueId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "Other",
                        "parentValueId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "name": "Student Clubs",
                        "parentValueId": null
                    }
                ],
                "isExportable": true
            },
            "FieldId": 81,
            "FieldGroupId": 12,
            "assignedValue": null
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 82,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "School Organization Name",
                "FieldGroupId": 12,
                "FieldGroupName": "College",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "T",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": 75,
                "availableValues": null,
                "isExportable": true
            },
            "FieldId": 82,
            "FieldGroupId": 12,
            "assignedValue": null
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 83,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "Gender",
                "FieldGroupId": 36,
                "FieldGroupName": "Demographics",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "T",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": 75,
                "availableValues": null,
                "isExportable": true
            },
            "FieldId": 83,
            "FieldGroupId": 36,
            "assignedValue": "Male"
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 84,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "Race",
                "FieldGroupId": 36,
                "FieldGroupName": "Demographics",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "T",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": 75,
                "availableValues": null,
                "isExportable": true
            },
            "FieldId": 84,
            "FieldGroupId": 36,
            "assignedValue": "Caucasian"
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 85,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "Age",
                "FieldGroupId": 36,
                "FieldGroupName": "Demographics",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "T",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": 75,
                "availableValues": null,
                "isExportable": true
            },
            "FieldId": 85,
            "FieldGroupId": 36,
            "assignedValue": "31"
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 70,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "Are you over 21?",
                "FieldGroupId": 16,
                "FieldGroupName": "RSVPs",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "S",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": null,
                "availableValues": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "no",
                        "parentValueId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "yes",
                        "parentValueId": null
                    }
                ],
                "isExportable": true
            },
            "FieldId": 70,
            "FieldGroupId": 16,
            "assignedValue": null
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 12,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "Opt-in to SMS messages",
                "FieldGroupId": 9,
                "FieldGroupName": "SMS OPT",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "B",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": null,
                "availableValues": null,
                "isExportable": false
            },
            "FieldId": 12,
            "FieldGroupId": 9,
            "assignedValue": null
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 75,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "Instagram Handle",
                "FieldGroupId": 34,
                "FieldGroupName": "Social Media",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "T",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": 75,
                "availableValues": null,
                "isExportable": true
            },
            "FieldId": 75,
            "FieldGroupId": 34,
            "assignedValue": null
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 79,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "Facebook Username",
                "FieldGroupId": 34,
                "FieldGroupName": "Social Media",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "T",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": 75,
                "availableValues": null,
                "isExportable": true
            },
            "FieldId": 79,
            "FieldGroupId": 34,
            "assignedValue": null
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 66,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "Upload ",
                "FieldGroupId": 31,
                "FieldGroupName": "Story Collection",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "S",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": null,
                "availableValues": [
    
                ],
                "isExportable": true
            },
            "FieldId": 66,
            "FieldGroupId": 31,
            "assignedValue": null
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 65,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "Story Collection ",
                "FieldGroupId": 31,
                "FieldGroupName": "Story Collection",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "B",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": null,
                "availableValues": null,
                "isExportable": true
            },
            "FieldId": 65,
            "FieldGroupId": 31,
            "assignedValue": null
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 64,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "Story Upload",
                "FieldGroupId": 31,
                "FieldGroupName": "Story Collection",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "T",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": 75,
                "availableValues": null,
                "isExportable": true
            },
            "FieldId": 64,
            "FieldGroupId": 31,
            "assignedValue": null
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 13,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "I would like to volunteer.",
                "FieldGroupId": 10,
                "FieldGroupName": "Volunteer",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "B",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": null,
                "availableValues": null,
                "isExportable": false
            },
            "FieldId": 13,
            "FieldGroupId": 10,
            "assignedValue": null
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 38,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "Text Opt-in (old)",
                "FieldGroupId": 10,
                "FieldGroupName": "Volunteer",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "B",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": null,
                "availableValues": null,
                "isExportable": true
            },
            "FieldId": 38,
            "FieldGroupId": 10,
            "assignedValue": null
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 62,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "Are you a high school student?",
                "FieldGroupId": 10,
                "FieldGroupName": "Volunteer",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "B",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": null,
                "availableValues": null,
                "isExportable": true
            },
            "FieldId": 62,
            "FieldGroupId": 10,
            "assignedValue": null
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 67,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "Are you a fan?",
                "FieldGroupId": 10,
                "FieldGroupName": "Volunteer",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "S",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": null,
                "availableValues": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "No",
                        "parentValueId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Yes",
                        "parentValueId": null
                    }
                ],
                "isExportable": true
            },
            "FieldId": 67,
            "FieldGroupId": 10,
            "assignedValue": null
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 68,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "Check here if you are a Spanish speaker",
                "FieldGroupId": 10,
                "FieldGroupName": "Volunteer",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "B",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": null,
                "availableValues": null,
                "isExportable": true
            },
            "FieldId": 68,
            "FieldGroupId": 10,
            "assignedValue": null
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 69,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "Did you purchase?",
                "FieldGroupId": 10,
                "FieldGroupName": "Volunteer",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "S",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": null,
                "availableValues": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Email",
                        "parentValueId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Phone call",
                        "parentValueId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "Text",
                        "parentValueId": null
                    }
                ],
                "isExportable": true
            },
            "FieldId": 69,
            "FieldGroupId": 10,
            "assignedValue": null
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 76,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "Contact 1",
                "FieldGroupId": 35,
                "FieldGroupName": "I don't know",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "T",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": 75,
                "availableValues": null,
                "isExportable": true
            },
            "FieldId": 76,
            "FieldGroupId": 35,
            "assignedValue": null
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 77,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "Test 2",
                "FieldGroupId": 35,
                "FieldGroupName": "I don't know",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "T",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": 75,
                "availableValues": null,
                "isExportable": true
            },
            "FieldId": 77,
            "FieldGroupId": 35,
            "assignedValue": null
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 78,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "Test 3",
                "FieldGroupId": 35,
                "FieldGroupName": "I don't know",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "T",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": 75,
                "availableValues": null,
                "isExportable": true
            },
            "FieldId": 78,
            "FieldGroupId": 35,
            "assignedValue": null
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 71,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "Test 4",
                "FieldGroupId": 32,
                "FieldGroupName": "I don't know",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "B",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": null,
                "availableValues": null,
                "isExportable": true
            },
            "FieldId": 71,
            "FieldGroupId": 32,
            "assignedValue": null
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 72,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "Test 5",
                "FieldGroupId": 32,
                "FieldGroupName": "I don't know",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "T",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": 75,
                "availableValues": null,
                "isExportable": true
            },
            "FieldId": 72,
            "FieldGroupId": 32,
            "assignedValue": null
        },
        {
            "Field": {
                "FieldId": 80,
                "FieldParentId": null,
                "FieldName": "Test 6",
                "FieldGroupId": 32,
                "FieldGroupName": "I don't know",
                "FieldGroupType": "Contacts",
                "FieldTypeId": "B",
                "isEditable": true,
                "maxTextboxCharacters": null,
                "availableValues": null,
                "isExportable": true
            },
            "FieldId": 80,
            "FieldGroupId": 32,
            "assignedValue": null
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the relevant JSON objects:

```
jq '.[] | select(.Field.FieldId | IN(83,84,85))' input.json
```

---

For future reference, please follow the http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve guidelines as much as possible.  It also usually helps if you show some evidence of the "research" you've completed, e.g. in the form of a failing program.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is too large to fit comfortably in memory, you could use the --stream option:

```
< input.json jq -n --stream '
  fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs)) | select(.Field.FieldId | IN(83,84,85))'
```